# ASP.NET Actionlink with glyphicon and text with different font

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, glyphicons

I want to present a button with `@Html.ActionLink` but i need to have my application font in the text.

With this code:

```
<span>
    @Html.ActionLink("  Create New", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" })
</span>
```

I get my button but the **Create New** text appears with the glyphicon font-family.

Putting the glyphicon classes in the span doesn't change anything

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You should not add the glyphicon class to the a-tag.

From the Bootstrap website:

> **Don't mix with other components**
>   Icon classes cannot be directly combined with other components. They should not be used along with other classes on the same element. Instead, add a nested `<span>` and apply the icon classes to the `<span>`.
>
> **Only for use on empty elements**
>   Icon classes should only be used on elements that contain no text content and have no child elements.

In other words the correct HTML for this to work the way you want would be: `<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">test <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a>`

This makes the `Html.ActionLink` helper unsuitable. Instead you could use something like:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")" class="btn btn-warning">
    link text 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Nice solution, one small comment to avoid browser display problems: use the <span> with a closing tag like this <span></span> instead of  <span />

Comment: Don't forget `aria-hidden="true"` on the `span` element.

Comment: Lovely answer. I was looking for the `@Url.Action` functionality too, but didn't know how to "search for it".... :)

Comment: but this won't work if you need to pass route value data, right?

Comment: In fact it does, `Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { MyRoute="data"})`

Answer (score 23):

This works for me in MVC 5:

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "EditResources", "NicheSites", new { ViewBag.dbc, item.locale, ViewBag.domainId, domainName = ViewBag.domaiName }, new {@class= "glyphicon glyphicon-edit" })
```

The first parameter cannot be empty or null or it will blow.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.

Comment: This works for an ActionLink that doesn't have text, i.e., a close button, add button, subtract button, etc. Which is exactly what I was looking for. The "accepted" answer is the best way if your button has text.

Thank you

Comment: Even if this works, it doesn't follow the Bootstrap docs, which state that the glyphicon class should not be combined with other classes or elements that contain text.

Answer (score 9):

It might be better to just write out the HTML rather than try to make it work with `HtmlHelper.ActionLink`...

```
<span>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Create")" class="btn btn-warning">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
        Create New
    </a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's mine. Inspired by Andrey Burykin

```
public static class BensHtmlHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString IconLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues, String iconName, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var linkMarkup = htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, routeValues, htmlAttributes).ToHtmlString();
        var iconMarkup = String.Format("<span class=\"{0}\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>", iconName);
        return new MvcHtmlString(linkMarkup.Insert(linkMarkup.IndexOf(@"</a>"), iconMarkup));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I should go with the approach of `@Url.Action` instead of `@Html.ActionLink`, se example code below:

```
<span>
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Create New</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple extension:

```
private static readonly String SPAN_FORMAT = "<span class=\"{0}\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>";
private static readonly String A_END = "</a>";
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues, String iconName, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var linkMarkup = htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, routeValues, htmlAttributes).ToHtmlString();
    if (!linkMarkup.EndsWith(A_END))
        throw new ArgumentException();

    var iconMarkup = String.Format(SPAN_FORMAT, iconName);
    return new MvcHtmlString(linkMarkup.Insert(linkMarkup.Length - A_END.Length, iconMarkup));
}
```

Usage:

```
Html.ActionLink(" ", "DeleteChart", new { Id = _.Id }, "glyphicon glyphicon-trash")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it!

```
@Html.ActionLink(" Cerrar sesión", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" , @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a try on this. Let me know if it is working .Thanks

```
<style>
   span.super a
  {
      font: (your application font) !important;
  }

</style>

<span class="super">
    @Html.ActionLink("  Create New", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" })
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using Html.BeginForm with a FormMethod.Get / FormMethod.Post

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new { Area = "" },
FormMethod.Get, htmlAttributes: new { title = "SomeTitle" }))
{   
   <button type="submit" class="btn-link" role="menuitem">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>Create New</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Worked for me.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class ="fa fa-plus">@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Create", "Home")</i></button>
```