# How to replace actionlink text with a glyphicon in @Html.ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

> I want to replace `X` with `glyphicon-trash`.

I am using `X` as a linktext.Which works for deleting an item.How to replace with a glyphicon.

Here is my code

```
 @Html.ActionLink(
                     "X",
                     "Delete",
                     "Grocery",
                     new { GroceryUsageID = item.GroceryUsageID, GroceryId = item.GroceryID },
                     new { @onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Grocery');"})
```

Comment: Can you describe your question little more in detailed? When you want to replace the text? If you want to replace, then have you tried with JQuery on client side?

Comment: I need to replace cross mark with trash glyphicon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Actionlink with glyphicon and text with different font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174013/asp-net-actionlink-with-glyphicon-and-text-with-different-font)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like following. Just add `@class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"` in `htmlAttributes` parameter and replace `X` with a `space`.

```
 @Html.ActionLink(
        " ",
        "Delete",
        "Grocery",
        new { GroceryUsageID = item.GroceryUsageID, GroceryId = item.GroceryID },
        new { @onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Grocery');", 
              @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash" })
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174013/asp-net-actionlink-with-glyphicon-and-text-with-different-font) ;)

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")" class="btn btn-warning">
    link text 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: I do not believe class="btn btn-warning" is necessary as glypicon-plus-sign is used for displaying + sign.

Answer (score 2):

This is my implementation for easier re-use

**Helper Method Extension class**

```
namespace Extensions {
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
    public static class HtmlExtensions {
        public static MvcHtmlString FALink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string action, string controller, string link_text, string fa_class, string btn_css_classes = "", string button_id = "", object route_values = null) {
                // declare the span                 
                TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
                span.AddCssClass($"fa fa-{fa_class}");
                span.MergeAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");         

                // declare the anchor tag
                TagBuilder anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
                // Add the href attribute to the <a> element
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(controller) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(action))
                    anchor.MergeAttribute("href", "#");
                else         
                    anchor.MergeAttribute("href", new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Action(action, controller, route_values));

                // Add the <span> element and the text to the <a> element
                anchor.InnerHtml = $"{span} {link_text}";
                anchor.AddCssClass(btn_css_classes);
                anchor.GenerateId(button_id);
                // Create the helper
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchor.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));    
        }
    }
}
```

***Make sure you include the namespace in the View so method is available***

Example usages in Razor View 
You can pass any route values you desire like any stock @Html helper using commas to separate values

using all parms:

```
@Html.FALink("ActionNameHere", "ControllerNameHere", "Back to List", "th-list", "btn btn-info", "btn_back_to_list", new {area="AreaNameHere"})
```

basic link type button:

```
@Html.FALink("ActionNameHere", "ControllerNameHere", "Back to List, "th-list")
```

basic link type button using bootstrap to color text

```
@Html.FALink("ActionNameHere", "ControllerNameHere", "Back to List", "th-list, "btn-info")
```

- While I use Font Awesome you could easily replace fa with bootstraps glyphicon class to use the bootstrap glyphicons
- If no controller or Action is passed in, it uses # as the link location so it will play nice with drop down interaction