# requested URL appends class= to the end

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I was following a post on here to add a glyph to a glyph to an ActionLink however I get "/Dashboard%20class=" this as my URL when all I want is to be redirected to the action that I specified without the %20class which is giving me errors

Here is the post I have been following [Insert Glyphicons bootstrap in @Html.ActionLink mvc asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049256/insert-glyphicons-bootstrap-in-html-actionlink-mvc-asp-net)

my HTML goes as follows:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard") class="btn btn-warning">
                        Dashboard
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" />
                        </a>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a `"` after the URL.

Therefore, the next word (`class`) is part of the URL, until the following `"`.

Answer (score 1):

I looks like you are missing a closing quote after your closing parenthesis for your Url.Action.  Otherwise it looks good.