# Can't add the Bootstrap Glyphicon Components for the MVC action link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink, glyphicons

Im try to add the   Bootstrap Glyphicon Components for  the MVC action link ,but i cant add this , please give me a solution.

**Action Link**

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Add", null/*"BlankEditorRow"*/, null, new { id = "addItem", @class = " btn-xs" })
```

**Plus Glyph**

```
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert Glyphicons bootstrap in @Html.ActionLink mvc asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049256/insert-glyphicons-bootstrap-in-html-actionlink-mvc-asp-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `glyphicon glyphicon-plus` class to `ActionLink` like following. Hope this will help you.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Add", null/*"BlankEditorRow"*/, null, new { id = "addItem", @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-xs" })
```